# Windows 10 as guest not activated inside virtualbox with Ubuntu 18.04 as host

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, license

I have a laptop with Windows 10 came pre-installed. I formatted my hd and disabled secure boot. Then installed Ubuntu 18.04
I then installed virtualbox with Windows 10 as guest. I went to setting and found that Windows 10 is not activated.
I also deleted secure keys info in bios accidentally.

Would my above steps rend me losing Windows 10 license? I need to use Visual Studio Code now. This could be a huge problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you activated a license with you Microsoft account. When yes, then simply login to Windows using your account. If you are trying to transfer OEM license to Virtualbox, then you are going the wrong way. For activating inside Virtualbox you will need a retail license. There are plenty of websites where you can get a license for a reasonable price. The question is whether you need it right now, because a standard installation of Windows 10 allows a trial period of 90 days...

Comment: Thanks........I didn't activate the license with my Microsoft account.

Comment: Then it is an OEM license though. You will need to look after retail license.

Comment: If you want to install it to the same bare metal, then there should be no problem with activation. You can install Windows10 alongside Ubuntu.

Comment: To confirm, is my OEM license gone? So now, I have to buy a retail license. Or is it that I can install Windows again after I format my hdd. Then my license would magically come back?

Comment: The license should come back, unless you change your CPU, HDD, graphics card or mainboard. The HW ID of your computer is stored on MS servers. Give it a try.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/637971/how-do-i-get-out-my-embedded-windows-8-key-from-a-linux-environment, you just need to input your own serial into your windows install

Answer (score -2):

You can use the license key of the machine, since it came preinstalled with Windows 10. To get the key use the following command:

```
sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

The license key will be the last line of the output.